# Best practices for building a serverless listener in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, paas

What are some best practices for building a serverless listeners of events in AWS? Let's say I would like to have a process which is constantly running and listening for events on a Kafka topic, or a queue for example.. I know I can build a listener process and run it from a EC2 instance, but I would prefer a serverless or at least a PaaS solution. I heard that AWS Lambdas are not good for this "continuously-running" pattern of execution... what are my options here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kafka Connect AWS Lambda sink connector? Or replace Kafka with Kinesis Data Streams.

Comment: You can run a docker container in AWS Fargate

Answer (score 0):

> I heard that AWS Lambdas are not good for this "continuously-running"
>   pattern of execution

This is not correct on AWS. Lambda is perfectly fit for your use case. Lambda can well handle streaming data from Kinesis or event from queue with high availability and scaling. You may read through the blog of AWS engineer and you will know that.

In your deployment scheme, Lambda may not be fit because it plays an active role instead of passive role (Lambda function execution will be triggered by other services instead). I think you can use EventBridge to listen from Kafka and then it will trigger lamba function. This way takes less development effort.